# Lua code to update player's position and screen

Tags: lua, constants

```
function update(event) -- check if the game is over
  if gameOver == true then
    return
  end
  fWait = (wTime > 0)
  if fWait then
    wTime = wTime – 0.01
    if wTime < 0 then
      wTime = 0
    end
    return
  end
  if hasAccel==true then
    local gx, gy = getAcceleration()
    fx = gx * filter + fx * (1-filter)
    fy = gy * filter + fy * (1-filter)
    updatePlayer(fx, fy)
  end
end
stage:addEventListener(Event.ENTER FRAME, update)
```

In above code, what is fx and fy? why is gx multiplied with a constant and fx with (1-constant)?

Comment: Where is the code from?

Comment: Apress learn Lua for IOS game development, Copter game development given at the end of book

Comment: `fx,fy` may be speed of some object, whose motion is controlled by screen tilting.  New point `(fx,fy)` will divide the segment `(fx,fy)-(gx,gy)` in the ratio `(1-filter):filter`.  Some sort of inertia emulation, I think.

Comment: I wonder what the last `end`ends.

Comment: Tip: Don't explicitly compare against true/false. It is mostly unneccessary and might slow your code, besides making it rigid.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will keep that in mind bUt I am still unclear about fx and fy and why is it multiplied by the constant , any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to say without more info but look at this:

```
local gx, gy = getAcceleration()
fx = gx * filter + fx * (1-filter)
```

This gets the acceleration of device. Based on fact that filter has no physical units, `fx` is an acceleration too (although sometimes developers take shortcuts and drop units by making assumptions about time periods and such but I don't think it is the case here).

- If filter is 0, new fx is just previous fx, everytime this `update(event)` is called (there is no info about how fx is computed, it may get updated in other parts of program too).
- If filter is 1, fx is gx (device accel) only, without any consideration of previous fx value.

So it looks like `filter` is a relative weight to give to device accel: when weight is zero, there is no device accel used so `fx` is just whatever has been computed so far; when weight is 1 then `fx` is entirely due to device accel so it is just `gx`. For all other intermediate values, updated `fx` is a proportional mixture of gravity and the previous value of fx: filter=0.25 means use 1/4 the effect of device accel, and the rest (1-1/4 or 3/4) the `fx` computed thus far.